# Recover original DAG from a topological order, using a test function

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

Let's T be a DAG (direct acyclic graph) where each node of the tree can be in a state 0 or 1.

I get a list, which represents a topological order of the DAG, where all of its nodes have state 0. I have boolean function `toggle` that acts on a node with the following semantics:

- If node `n` has state 1, `toggle(n)` changes its status to 0 and returns `true`.
- If node `n` has state 0, then `toggle(n)` changes its status to 1 and returns `true` if and only if all of its direct and indirect parents on the original DAG has also state 1 right now. Otherwise, `toggle(n)` returns `false` and the state of the node isn't changed.

In my problem, I have the list but I don't have the original DAG, and I want, by using the function `toggle(n)` as a test function, to recover the original DAG.

Every solution I have think of so far have some form of combinatorial explosion. Is there any polynomial time solution for this? Does this problem or some similar problem have a name?

My initial approach involves to `toggle(n)` all nodes and "store" those that succeed. That way I get the "roots" of the original DAG, but any other thing that I came up with involves some sort of combinatorial explosion of "trying every possible combination".

Comment: You forgot to post (as opposed to "roughly describe") your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: A "tree" with multiple roots and multiple parents is not a tree.  It's a DAG.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Yes you're right. Fixed now. Thank you.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Isn't any acyclic graph a tree? Regardless of if it's multi-rooted or directed, etc.

Comment: No.  A tree is connected, and in a directed tree, every node except the root has a single predecessor.   An *undirected* graph without cycles is also a tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudocode:

```
upstreams = dictionary()  # node -> upstream nodes
upstream_set = set()

while len(upstream_set) < n:
    for current_node in all_nodes not in upstream_set:
        # at each iteration, find the minimal upstream coverage for current_node

        set_all_upstream_set_nodes_to_one()
        flip current_node to one()
        if current_node flip is unsuccessful:  # returned false
            continue  # upstream is not yet complete for this node

        # minimize upstream for current_node
        upstreams[current_node] = set()
        for upstream_node in upstream_set:
            flip upstream_node to zero
            flip current node back and forth
            if flip is unsuccessful:
                upstreams[current_node].add(upstream_node)
                flip upstream_node back to one
            # otherwise, upstream_node is not relevant for current_node

        # found minimal upstream coverage
        upstream_set.add(current_node)
```

The resulting `upstreams` should be sufficient for topological sorting.

Complexity: outer `while+for` should be at most O(n^2) (worst case: a single line), inner `for` should be O(n) - O(n^3) overall.

Comment: In your `for` condition, did you mean "current_node in all_nodes not in upstream_set"?

Comment: @ABu Yes, sorry about that. I mean, all nodes except those in upstream_set - and in the cycle each of those nodes is referred as `current_node`.